# How to update the information shown on a WPF Control dependent on its size

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I'm working on a custom WPF control based on ContentControl that is supposed to show more less important information as its size increases. Basically the Control contains a grid that can have more columns when the control has a sufficient width to display that information and less columns otherwise.

Therefore I somehow need to override some event i guess in which I can determine the actual size of the control and then rebuild its Grid thats defined in the ContentTemplate.

So the actual questions are:
Which event should I override to achieve this? And
How do I gain access to the Grid defined in the DataTemplate? In fact this one sounds a bit wrong as logic and UI should be separated and one should be able to replace the entire ControlTemplate without affecting the logic behind it...

Regards,
Max

Comment: Maybe you will approach `Thumb`, by hold on which you can increase / decrease the size of the control. Let me know if you need an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider posting us more code when you ask such specific questions.

> *Which event should I override to achieve this?*

You seem to be asking for SizeChanged event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Any FE (FrameworkElement) has it therefore you will be able to subscribe to it.

---

> *And How do I gain access to the Grid defined in the DataTemplate?*

In order to find something inside a template you could follow this constillation:

```
this.Template.FindName("theScrollViewer", this) as ScrollViewer
```

In my example I seek for a element with the name theScrollViewer

**EDIT:**

There is a great explaination here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586(v=vs.110).aspx

**EDIT2:**

[TemplatePart(Name="PART_ContentHost", Type=typeof(FrameworkElement))]

TemplatePart is just an attribute that visual studio will use to show you how you should give names to your controls inside the template.

---

This method is doing the same as I showed you above.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    anchor = Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", this) as FrameworkElement;
}
```

Comment: Hi hedgehog, thanks for the reply, I considered posting code but I decided not to, so people wouldn't try to build on a maybe wrong approach. I also came across `TemplateParts` [here]http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-part-names). Is there any considerable difference between your and his approach and coming back to my original question, doesn't that violate the "separate logic and UI" law?

Comment: You are doing all fine. Take a look at my new edit in my answer.